# error in validating if validation true it store in cart_id

Tags: django, serialization

[adject error in vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyUOy.png)Error line on self.validated_data
if validation true it will store data in cart_id
error does't cost me any problem in web page

```
class CreateOrderSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    cart_id = serializers.UUIDField()
    def save(self,**kwargs):
        print(self.validated_data['cart_id'])
        print(self.context['user_id'])
        (customer,created )= Customer.objects.get_or_create(user_id=self.context['user_id'])
        Order.objects.create(customer=customer)
```

tried multiple method

```
 cart_id = self.validated_data
         print(cart_id)
```

but nothing work

Comment: I'm working on a full answer for you, but just as a first minor recommendation: Since what you are trying to do here is create a serializer that creates an object. A `ModelSerializer` might be what you're looking for since it handles a lot of the validation and creation functionality for you.

Comment: When I recreate your code shown in the image linked, I don't get any errors. It seems to be working fine. Could you please elaborate on what the issue is and what you would like to achieve? Also, what versions of python, django and django-rest-framework are you using?